# SwiftUI download pdf from API and open automatically in Files / external PDF viewer

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to download a PDF from an API call, and have it open automatically upon download in the PDF viewer (e.g. in Files). I do not want it to be displayed in-app.

The file does download, and I can find it in `Files > On My iPhone > AppName`, but it doesn't open automatically. How can I achieve that?

```swift
func downloadContractAgreement() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "[redacted]" else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let keychain = Keychain()
        var token = keychain["authToken"] ?? "none"
        request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: request) { localURL, response, error in
            if let localURL = localURL {
                let destinationURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("downloaded2.pdf")
                
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: localURL, to: destinationURL)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(destinationURL) { success in
                            if !success {
                                print("Failed to open \(destinationURL)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("File error: \(error)")
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: May be you can try using the share sheet.

Comment: @PtitXav, I can do that, but even from the share sheet there's no way to just open it. It just gives the option to Save to Files or share etc. Is there no way to just open the file directly?

Comment: The easiest would be to open a PDFView in your app.

Comment: May be try to find the URL for the Books app.